# Newtonsoft dependency problem with Syncfusion with ElectronNET

Tags: electron, blazor, syncfusion

I have a standard .NET 5 Blazor Server project which uses the [Syncfusion DataGrid](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/datagrid/getting-started/). After adding the required Syncfusion Nuget packages and building I found there is a dependency upon Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.0.0.

As there is no version 12.0.0 available on Nuget I installed 12.0.3 and re-built. Running the application as a Blazor Server works fine.

I actually want to run the project as an Electron desktop app and have been using [ElectronNET](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET) to do that pretty successfully until trying to use the DataGrid component.

I can compile and run the Electron app using `electronize start` but as soon as I browse to the page which contains the DataGrid I get the error:

```
stdout: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified.
      System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified.
      File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
```

Can anyone offer any advice on how I might overcome this?

Comment: Did this get solved?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, did you get anywhere with it?

Comment: @RobH If I remember correctly the error message turned out to be a red herring (false error) and the problem was actually to do with my component lifecycle: one or more of my component properties/parameters was null upon initial loading. I made sure all properties/parameters were set to empty or zero, etc. and the error went away.

Comment: @phil - ah, a different issue to me but sounds similar. I'm sure the correct dll is being copied so I think I'm in red herring territory too. Thanks for the reply.